# How can I shorten a BasedOn style

Tags: c#, wpf, refactoring, styles

I'm currently making a "base style" for our application. I started by making a "base style" for our buttons, which will be a nice double-gradient (I created a template with 2 rows, and both rows have a two-point gradient).

So, the base button works fine, now I want to create other buttons based on that style.

This is the code for the base button:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource OffWhiteBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GrayBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="TopBorder" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Background="{DynamicResource TopGrayGradientBrush}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BottomBorder" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" Background="{DynamicResource BottomGrayGradientBrush}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TopBorder" Value="{DynamicResource TopGrayGradientBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BottomBorder" Value="{DynamicResource BottomGrayGradientBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TopBorder" Value="{DynamicResource TopBlueGradientBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BottomBorder" Value="{DynamicResource BottomBlueGradientBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I create a second button I can do it "BasedOn" the other style:

```
<Style x:Key="RedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
 ...
```

Inside the grid I've named my gradients: topborder and bottomborder. The problem is that I need to duplicate the code in order to be able to set any code, because the redbuttonStyle doesn't "know" topborder or bottomborder:

```
<Style x:Key="RedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GrayBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="TopBorder" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Background="{DynamicResource TopGrayGradientBrush}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BottomBorder" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" Background="{DynamicResource BottomGrayGradientBrush}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TopBorder" Value="{DynamicResource TopGrayGradientBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BottomBorder" Value="{DynamicResource BottomGrayGradientBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TopBorder" Value="{DynamicResource TopRedGradientBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BottomBorder" Value="{DynamicResource BottomRedGradientBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem here is that I've pretty much repeated the entire style, whilst I only want to change the two gradients on the IsMouseOver event

How should I handle this?

PS. I've looked at this [WPF -- override style colors, best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282492/wpf-override-style-colors-best-practice), but I can't figure out the TemplateBinding :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a technique where you define properties specific to your theme in a separate class and then bind to those properties from your templates. Please see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070421/wpf-styles-template-inheritance).